# RegEx to convert double quotes to single at the beginning and at the end

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

i have a variable which stores the whole html content like :-

getcontent =`"<table style="height: 1000px; ; width: 500px;" border="1"> <tbody> <tr> <td>[<span>Assignment(for) name</span>]</td> <td>[<span>Total No of staff-months of the assignment</span>]</td> </tr> <tr> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr> </tbody> </table> "`

now i want to convert the frst and the end double quote with single quote.

what regex can be used so that the getcontent converts to :-

```
'<table style="height: 1000px; ; width: 500px;" border="1"> <tbody> <tr> <td>[<span>Assignment(for) name</span>]</td> <td>[<span>Total No of staff-months of the assignment</span>]</td> </tr> <tr> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr> </tbody> </table> '
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use anchors for the beginning and end of the string:

```
getcontent = getcontent.replace(/(^"|"$)/g, "'");
```

`^` represents the beginning of the string and `$` the end.

This assumes that you actually have a string that contains a beginning end ending `"`, not a string that is (syntactically) enclosed in `"`, in which case your input is not valid, due to unescaped `"` within the string.

Comment: I just tested it. What do you get instead?

Comment: You tested with the same example i gave ? i am  not getting any change.

Comment: Ahhh. I inserted `'` around your input string. Because right now, your input string does not have **any** quotes at the beginning and end (because the double quotes start and end the string and are not part of it). Try alerting getcontent without calling `replace` and you will see.

Comment: Oh actually my question was to remove all the html tags inside a square bracket... for that i am using the regex http://jsfiddle.net/uZRQt/1/ 

which is working fine if i change the double quote at the end to single quote. i am totally new regex

Comment: Since those quotes are not part of your string you cannot remove them with a regex. The reason why it is not working with `"` is that there are `"` which end the string. You would have escape them with `\"`. But since the not-working version is not valid JavaScript there is no programmatical solution to this.

Comment: Ok.... but http://jsfiddle.net/uZRQt/1/ can be used to remove html tags between the sqaure brackets but not blank spaces  such as [&nbsp;Approximate Value of Contract(of)]

can u help me with teh regex for that

Comment: Please post that as a new question ;)